# How to restrict a coupon code not to be applicable on the already discounted item?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise

How can I restrict a coupon code from being applied to a product which is already discounted.

That means if the product is having the special price or some catalog price rule is applicable on it.Then coupon code should not be applicable on the products.

Is this possible in Magento?

Comment: As usual, there are modules at the magento connect, that allow to restrict coupon to discount products with special price.

Comment: @Amasty Can you suggest some if you ever used one of these?

Comment: This site restricts self advertizing, but if you are asking, here is the link: http://amasty.com/special-promotions.html . There is a setting for such case as it's very common issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first part is not possible with default Magento. (Restricting products which already have a special price). A workaround could be to put all discounted products into a category and exclude products of that category in the shopping cart price rule.

The second part (restricting products which a discount by another rules has already been applied to) should be possible with a combination of priority and "Stop Further Rules Processing" set to yes.